# Which collision resolution scheme in Hashing is inherently safe from generating a 0 increment

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

What is the best collision resolution technique in Hashing which is safe from generating a zero increment? Why?

Comment: By "zero increment," I assume you're talking about using some sort of open addressing scheme (linear probing, double hashing, etc.) and ensuring that when you take steps of the given size, you do so in a way that never risks having the step size be equal to zero?

Comment: yes. you are right

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "best?" Standard linear probing is very fast in practice.